# What is the best dropbox compatible iPad app for MS office documents?

Tags: ipad, ios, ms-office, dropbox

It's pretty simple. I just got an iPad and want to get the best app to edit word documents that I have saved in my dropbox. There are many options: pages, quick office, docs to go, office2.

I am looking to be able to browse documents within DropBox and tap edit to open them in the editor. I'll make a few changes and expect to be able to tap save and have it automatically update DropBox.

Comment: Dropbox Integration is pretty basic - you either use the default folder, it picks a folder or you can pick a folder. It's just webDAV as well. Do make a stab at editing the criteria for best word editor. Best for me is iA Writer simple - best for another might be a kitchen sing of features. Best is so vague and subjective without context of you and your expectations.

Comment: For me, "best" is: I can view documents in the dropbox app, tap "edit" to open them in an editing program, make some changes and hitting "save" will automatically update the dropbox.

Comment: Excellent - I've edited that into the question. Feel free to add more information by editing your question if you don't get the answer you like after a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a professional writer, I've tried out a bunch of these apps, and I prefer Dataviz’s [Documents to Go Premium](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/iphone/index.html), which creates and edits Microsoft Office documents (Word, Excel, PowerPoint). The great thing about the Premium version (and justifies the extra $6 over the basic version) is that it connects with the Dropbox online storage service. Documents to Go does a good job of editing Word documents, including maintaining styles, etc.

Comment: I'll second Documents to Go as an awesome product that makes a lot of people appreciate the premium version. It's a great value.

Answer (score 0):

My father uses DocsToGo and he´s happy. But he doesn't have a mac. But he said that it works very well for him.

Answer (score 0):

Documents To Go now trumps QuickOffice after QO dropped support for Dropbox. Also has a more friendly and flexible interface.

Answer (score -1):

Quickoffice is a great app, but it no longer supports Dropbox.

Comment: Which means it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Are you meaning to tell someone to rule this out as a choice or that it's so good that you should ditch dropbox and use another solution that you propose? (_i.e. at least provide a complete solution when you're going to change a premise of the question_)